# speeding up 'apt-get update' to speed up Docker image builds

Tags: docker, apt

I want to add `curl` to a Docker image, and I'm using the following commands to in a Dockerfile to do so:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl ca-certificates -y
```

My issue is that the initial update takes a pretty long time to run (2 min), so while I'm debugging my Dockerfile, iteration is slow. In particular when I make changes before the `RUN apt-get update`, which invalidate Docker's image cache.

Is there any way to be more selective with `apt-get update`, so it only updates enough to index where to download `curl`? Or some other technique I can use to speed up my Docker builds?

Here is the whole Dockerfile,

```
FROM postgres:9.6.10
ADD data/tsvs.tar.gz /standard_data
COPY postgres/*.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl ca-certificates -y
RUN curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.6-postgis-scripts -y
```

I'm currently making changes to the SQL files in postgres/*.sql, hence the cache invalidation.

Comment: Could you give us the whole Dockerfile? There may be ways to take advantage of Docker cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image is organized in layers and each layer depends on the previous later. Layers are also cached for speed.

When you run the build again do keep checks if the ch ckecksum of a command line in the dockerfile changed. If it didn't then it pulls the layer from cache. But if it did then it rebuilds the later and all successive layers.

In your particular case the ADD command generates a new layer each time you make a change and that triggers all the successive layers to be rebuilt.

By move moving the installation before you fix this issue.

You should also put all the installations on 1 line and clean the apt cache when you are done.

```
RUN apt-get install curl ca-certificates -y && \
  curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - && \
  apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.6-postgis-scripts -y && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/apt && \
  apt-get clean
```

Comment: Note that cleaning up after `apt` may not be necessary if you are using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to simply copy over the build artifacts you are interested in.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sed` to replace the `sources.list` links with mirrors so it always choose the best mirrors when running apt.

For Ubuntu, you can add this to your docker file before running apt,

```
RUN sed -i 's/htt[p|ps]:\/\/archive.ubuntu.com\/ubuntu\//mirror:\/\/mirrors.ubuntu.com\/mirrors.txt/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This would relpace the default `http(s)://archive.ubuntu.com` with `mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt` in your sources.list file in-place using sed.

Tested for working on Ubuntu 20.04 docker.

Note: You might need to install `ca-certificates` to remove certificate errors when running apt.

Answer (score 1):

If I move the `curl` install stuff to before the parts that I'm changing, the cache will hit more often. My new file is

```
FROM postgres:9.6.10
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl ca-certificates -y
RUN curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.6-postgis-scripts -y

ADD data/tsvs.tar.gz /standard_data
COPY postgres/*.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY postgres/subsetting.s* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

h/t to Caleb H. for making think of this with his comment.

Comment: Just a note: it is a docker antipattern to not have all apt-* commands in same RUN. Please see this for details: https://runnable.com/blog/9-common-dockerfile-mistakes

Comment: It's not an antipattern if the alternative is super difficult to do in non-trivial cases, e.g. in generated Dockerfiles that assemble the desired functionality from multiple components, each needing to install its own dependencies.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski we may use multi-stage builds in this case, I guess?

Comment: @ziuyang No. The work done by apt-* commands when installing a package is nontrivial, and ALL of it must be done when installing a package in the final image in order to be sure that it is installed correctly and nothing is missing. "Install in intermediate, dumb copy to final" WILL cause issues. THAT is the antipattern. It's OK to build from source in the intermediate, _producing_ a package that will then be installed in final using proper installation tools, but using the latter is NOT avoidable.

Answer (score 0):

[This post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/d0n6ip/apt_is_really_slow/ezav2mw?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) suggests that copying your local apt `sources.list` to the container with `COPY sources.list /etc/apt/` may help the container's `apt update` to use local mirrors which may speeds things up